# Is there a good system to tell or mark which picture are in a group of bracket?

Tags: bracketing, fujifilm-x-t20

I have taken a bunch of shots. Some of them are intended for bracketing.

But when it comes to post-processing, the photos confuse me because I cannot confidently tell which group of three are from a bracket shot. Here is an example:

[image]

Is there any good system or best practice that can help tell the group of photo apart of other normal snapshots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a picture of your left hand.
Yes, really.
Before you bracket you take a picture of your left hand indicating the number of shots that will be in the bracketing series.

What if it's more than 5 shots?
Well, use the fist as one number, open back hand as one, open palm as one, take a picture of your feet.
It's all up to you. Just don't unzip to make 6. Someone will find it offending.

Comment: That's a great idea, but for one thing. My hand would be part of of the bracket, or I'd have to have three pictures of my hand, or switch bracketing off & on again.... My camera will only do brackets in 'sets of three', no other way :\

Comment: Unless you plan on holding down the button and taking several brackets continuously, the timestamps contained in the metadata should be an extremely good indicator of which shots go with each bracketed group.

Comment: also, cameras pretty much write the filenames monotonically increasing. Even without timestamps, file sort order (with files of the same extension) will get you the proper sequence.

Comment: @Tetsujin mine only takes as many pictures as I ask it to do. have you tried to just click once?

Comment: If I just click once, it takes the first of the bracket set. No matter how long I wait after that, the next picture will be the 2nd bracket. I often reach the point where I just take a few to see where in the sequence it is, then discard once I know I'm back to 'one'. It's quicker than turning bracketing off/on again. Nikon D5500, consumer-level.

Comment: @Tetsujin in all fairness I have not thought much about that. Will have to try it, but a quick off/on on the power switch should clear that memory.

Comment: @Andreas - yeah, you'd think… but no. It remembers where it was. [I just tested to be sure]

Comment: Battery out and the camera submerged in water? :-)

Comment: American Sign Language has single-hand numbers for every combination 1-10, you probably want to sign them "backwards" so that they face the camera when you're doing them.

Comment: @CRDrost I'm quite sure all languages do. But to not complicate things I figured it was easier to make your "own language". But some sign language use motion also. I know the number 9 (or 10) has a twist in my language, that's a bit complicated to do on a image.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that changing the bracketing pattern from 0, -, + (which is what most cameras seem to use by default) to -, 0, + helps me to more easily identify bracketed sequences when looking at thumbnails or "filmstrips" at the bottom of the screen when reviewing images.

The brightest "+" image is almost always the most easily recognizable one and marks the end of each bracketed sequence.

If your camera allows you to set the order of the bracketed sequence from darkest to brightest (or brightest to darkest) instead of placing the center exposure first, try it and see if you find it helpful.